# Tengo problema con el responsive web

Tags: html5, css3, web, diseño

Al momento de agregar los MEDIA QUERIES para que no salga la barra vertical, igual me sale. Como puedo solucionar este inconveniente, soy nuevo.

Tiene un HEADER y también su NAV, al igual que una SECCION DE PRESENTACION. Revise cada elemento mediante el buscado, revisando el ancho de cada uno para visualizar si uno sobre sale del tamaño del ancho para una pantalla móvil, pero todos estaban bien. Dejo el codigo, para quien sea la persona que me pueda brindar su ayuda, lo pueda copiar y emular y ver el error que yo aun no puedo ver. De antemano, les agradesco.

CODIGO HTML

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Store</title>
    <link rel="preload" as="style" href="Estilo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Estilo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Overpass:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

<body>  

    <div class="cabecera-principal">
        <div class="cabecera">
            <header>
                <a href="Inicio.html"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="Logotipo"></a>
            </header>
        </div >
        
        <div class="nav-contenedor">
            <nav class="navegacion">
                <a href="#">Inicio</a>
                <a href="Tienda.html">Tienda</a>
                <a href="#">Quienes somos</a>
                <a href="#">Contactanos</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

    <section class="presentacion">
        <div class="pres-contenedor">
            <h2>Lideres en ropa de marca</h2>
            <p>En <b>FRONTED STORE</b> nos enfocamos en ofrecerte
                la mejorar calidad y mejor precio...
            </p>
            
            <a href="#"><button class="boton">Conocer mas....</button></a>
        </div>

        <div class="img-contenedor">
            <img src="/img/conoce-mas.png" alt="Imagen de muestra" class="img-presentacion">
        </div>  
    </section>


</body>




</html>
```

CODIGO CSS3

```
    /* GLOBALES */
html {
    font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;

    box-sizing: border-box;

    font-size: 62.5%;   
  }
  *, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
  }

  p{
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

img{
    width:100%;  
}

h1, h2, h3{
    text-align: center;
}

/* FIN GLOBALES */

/* Navegacion y Header */
.logo{
    width: 15rem;
    height: 15rem;
    transition: 300ms;
    padding: 2rem;
    margin-right: 31rem;
}


.cabecera-principal{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: brown;
    
}

.cabecera{
    width: 15rem;
    text-align: center;
    
    padding: 1rem;
}

.nav-contenedor{
    
    width: min(55rem,100%);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}

a{
    
    transition: 400ms;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    
}

.navegacion a:hover{
    background-color: white;
    
    color: black;
    
}

.logo:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
    
}

@media (max-width: 480px){
    .cabecera-principal{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .nav-contenedor{
        background-color: white;
    }

    .nav-contenedor a{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: white;
        color:black;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/* CUERPO PRESENTACION */

.presentacion{
    padding: 1.5rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    column-gap: 7rem;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(240, 216, 2);
    height: 100%;
}

.img-presentacion{
    height: 40rem;
    
   
    
}

.pres-contenedor{
    height: -5rem;
    width: min(30rem, 100%);
    padding-left: 2rem;
}

.pres-contenedor h2{
    font-size: 3.3rem;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgb(66, 66, 66);
}

.boton{
    background:white;
    border:none;
    border-radius:1rem;
    padding: 2rem 3rem;
    margin: 2rem 0rem;
    transition: 300ms;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.boton:hover{
    background-color: rgb(38, 38, 184);
    color:white;
}

@media (max-width: 480px){
    .presentacion{
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .presentacion .boton{
        background-color:rgb(38, 38, 184) ;
        color:white;
        width: 95%;
    }

    .img-presentacion{
        width: 40rem;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿A qué barra vertical te refieres? Por favor, describe más detalladamente lo que quieres hacer y lo que sale. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios puntos a comentar sobre el código, pero iré a los principales:

**EMPAQUETAMIENTO EXCESIVO**

No es algo que influya en lo que  preguntas, pero es importante mencionarlo para que mejores la claridad de tu código. Veamos el siguiente fragmento:

```
<div class="cabecera-principal">
        <div class="cabecera">
            <header>
                <a href="Inicio.html"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="Logotipo"></a>
            </header>
        </div >
```

Sería mejor hacer

```
<div class="cabecera-principal">
        <!--cabecera = header-->
        <header>
            <a href="Inicio.html"><img class="logo" src="img/coche1.jpg" alt="Logotipo"></a>
        </header>
```

¿Para qué quieres envolver el header en otro header? Esto te pasa mucho a lo largo del código: creas contenedores cuyas funciones pueden ser adquiridas perfectamente por el inmediato contenedor hijo sin modificaciones o con mínimas modificaciones, proporcionando así menos clases en CSS y menos etiquetas HTML, es decir, mayor claridad del código y de lo que hace cada parte.

Evidentemente, el código CSS del div "cabecera" pasa a ser del header.

**MALA INDENTACIÓN**

Mira tu código: ¿no notas que los márgenes son irregulares y hay saltos de línea indebidos? Para facilitar la lectura del código debes respetar una correcta indentación del código. Corrige ese aspecto o muchos sufrirán con tu código el día de mañana (tú el primero).

Por cierto, esto tampoco afecta al problema.

**¡CUIDADO CON LAS MEDIDAS RELATIVAS!**

Ahora sí, vamos al origen de tu problema. Fíjate que tu clase .logo tiene un margin de 31 rem.

¿Qué es un rem? Un rem es una proporción 1:1 con respecto al tamaño de la fuente tipográfica raíz. ¿Qué significa esto? Significa que si el navegador tiene, por definición (y no lo que tú definas) un tamaño de 16px para la letra, entonces 1rem son 16px.

Esto implica que tu margen derecho para el logo es de 31x16=496px, lo cual supera, claramente, el ancho de la pantalla de la media query (y eso que no hemos sumado el ancho del logo y lo que tiene a su izquierda).

¿Cómo solucionarlo? Hay tres opciones:

**(1)** Reducir el margen derecho. Por ejemplo, ponlo a 2rem.

**(2)** Esta es la que  más recomiendo. ¡No uses rem o em como medidas para contenedores! Como ya dije, rem (y también em) son medidas pensadas para fuentes tipográficas, no para contenedores (es decir, div, section, img...y sus respectivas medidas como margin, padding, etc.). Usa porcentajes o píxeles. ¿Píxeles? Sí, píxeles. Si lees código de otros programadores, te sorprenderá lo habitual que es usar píxeles donde la lógica dice que deberías usar medidas relativas, y no absolutas. Esto es cuestión de que pruebes cositas y leas código de otra gente.

**(3)** Para este caso en concreto, puedes quitar el margen derecho a la clase logo y verás que todo va de maravilla.

**En resumen**: el margen derecho de la clase logo obliga a "estirar" la pantalla para que este quepa. La solución es reducir dicho margen.

Espero haberte ayudado. Cualquier duda, ponla en los comentarios de esta respuesta y estaré encantado de ayudar nuevamente. ¡Suerte!